# I'm planning on taking an Introduction to Geometry class next term. What should I expect?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

For reference, I'm heading in to my second year of my bachelor of Computer Science. I'm required to take a second year level math course and I was thinking about taking Introduction to Geometry. It says that the course is intended for a general audience. What kinds of things will I be learning if I take it and will it be worth it? If not, are there more relevant courses I could take?

Edit:

The description of the course says: "An introduction to classical geometry; Euclidean plane geometry; plane tiling; polytopes in three and four dimensions; curved surfaces; Euler characteristic."

Comment: It depends on what you mean with relevant. If you want something to complement your studies, you might want to take a course in combinatorics for example?

Comment: Your university should have a description of this course, which will be a lot more reliable than people here guessing based solely on the title of the course. Different people will associate *very* different things with such a general title. If you have trouble making sense of such a course description, feel free to edit your question to include a link to the description, then we can help you decode the terms in question.

Comment: I find that being able to think geometrically is very useful and understanding the logical structure of geometry proofs is helpful. BTW, haven't you already taken a course in geometry in high school?

Comment: @Marc Ah, when I said relevant I did mean something to complement my field. I'm also interested in game design and I've already taken an introductory Linear Algebra course.

Comment: @MvG I see, I'll do that now

Comment: @martycohen I'm not sure it's part of the curriculum where I live cause I don't remember taking a proper course for geometry. It was probably part of a math course from grade 10

Comment: I would recommend discussing this with a CS professor or even the professor for said geometry course (if one is listed); someone experienced in whatever CS specialty you're interested in would also probably be able to offer a better perspective. Anything dealing with intense graphics would obviously require linear algebra; number theory would be very useful for crypto; there are surely others that I can't think of right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question sounds like [MATH 2210](http://calendar.carleton.ca/search/?P=MATH%202210) at Carleton University. If you [search for that](https://www.google.com/search?q=math+2210+carleton) you will find e.g. [assignments from 2009](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~cgarner/) which will give you a more detailed idea of the topics you'd cover. It appears pretty hands-on to me. Given the wide range of topics, chances are that there is at least one you can put to use at some point of your career.

Whether the knowledge is “worth it” depends on what you plan to do in the long run. Geometry is useful for things like computer graphics, computer vision, CAD, but less useful if you concentrate on say data bases, web applications or theoretic questions of computability. CS is a broad field.

In general there should be people at your university who are better suited to give advice on this decision. They would know the alternatives you can choose from, and probably also past experiences from other students.